# Safe usage of .FirstorDefault()?

Tags: c#, .net

When using Enumerable.FirstorDefault(), do I need to always catch the **ArumentNullException** that can be thrown when the collection operated on is **null**?

In the past I've always just done something like this:

```
WorkflowColorItemType associatedColor = ColorItems
    .Where(ci => ci.AssociatedState == WorkflowStateStatus.NotStarted)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (associatedColor != null)
{
    this.ColorItems.CurrentColor = associatedColor;
}
```

In the context of this code snippet, I would never expect ColorItems to be null but is it good practice to be enclosing every instance of  snippets like this in try catch blocks so I can handle the off chance that the ColorItems collection might be null?

Comment: You can directly invoke FirstOrDefault in place of Where, it is exactly the same thing.

Comment: A side note, I don't think that the .FirstOrDefault() call will ever cause the exception. It's the .Where() that's going to be operating on a (potentially) null value.

Comment: I wouldn't wrap it in a try catch block.  You can always just check to see if the collection is equal to null before running the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't expect the collection to ever be empty, and *it would be an error in your program* for it to be empty, then don't use `FirstOrDefault` in the first place, use `First`.  Since it's not an expected situation for you to be in *you want to draw attention to the problem* because it's a sign that something is wrong.

If it's entirely valid for the collection to be empty, and you want to use the first item only if there is at least one item, then using `FirstOrDefault` and providing a null check is fine.

Apply the same logic to the collection being null, and not empty.  If it is *expected* that the collection be allowed to be null, then check for it using an `if`.  If it's *not* expected that the collection be allowed to be `null` (which is generally the case for most uses of collections) then you shouldn't check, and you *want* the exception to be thrown as it will draw attention to the bug in the code that is supposed to populate that collection.  Trying to catch the exception and move on is trying to obscure the bug *which prevents you from finding and fixing it*.

Comment: This is incorrect, because even though ColorItems may never be null, the .Where() that is taking place before the .FirstOrDefault() may result in an empty set.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung what is wrong with calling FirstOrDefault on an empty set?

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Yes, it might return an empty set, in the general case.  If your program logic assumes that something will always be yielded, for your specific situation, you should use `First`.  If your program assumes that there are valid inputs that will not yield any results, then you should use `FirstOrDefault` to code around it.

Comment: @Selman22 - Nothing, but if you called First() on an empty set, you will get an exception, but if you call FirstOrDefault, you will get null. My comment was not in regards to that anyways - it was in regards to the fact that he is saying to use First because ColorItems will never be null. But ColorItems being null or not has absolutely nothing to do with the FirstOrDefault, since FirstOrDefault is not being called on ColorItems, it is being called on the IEnumerable generated by the .Where().

Comment: @Servy - His assumption is that ColorItems will never be null (it may still be empty). But even if his assumption is that ColorItems will never be empty, you can't assume that the .Where will never be empty, since you are limiting the results of ColorItems in the .Where.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung That depends entirely on the domain of the program.  If it's expected, given the problem domain, that the filter could potentially filter out all items, then the code should support that, which means not using methods like `First`.  If, in the specific problem domain at hand, it would be considered a bug in the code for nothing to pass the filter, then using `First` *is the best solution* because you don't want to hide or obscure a bug in the code; you want to throw an exception when in a situation that you know you shouldn't be in, so that you can fix the bug.

Comment: I invite you all to have a look at the docs for `FirstOrDefault`.  It *will* throw null if the IEnumerable<T> it's querying is null.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Kyralessa I invite you to read my 3rd paragraph, addressing that case, in which I state that if the collection being null is a *valid* use case that the code should check for it before querying it.

Comment: @Servy, thank you for the invitation.  I agree with you, except for this one caveat: A null collection is *never* a valid case.  An *empty* collection, yes.  But not a null one.

Comment: @Kyralessa I disagree.  I find that it's *usually* not a valid case, and it's almost certainly not a valid case in this particular example, but there are exceptional situations in which a null collection is valid; it's simply important that those situations not "leak" the null collection into the situations in which a null collection is not valid.

Comment: @Servy, I cannot think of a single such case.  Can you?  Unlike most objects (e.g. what would a default `Customer` look like?), there's a very obvious default case for a collection: An *empty* collection.  There's *never* a reason for passing null when a collection is expected.  If you can think of a legitimate need for this, I would be interested to know what it is.

Comment: @Kyralessa The first thing that comes to mind is something that is leveraging lazy initialization.  If it's `null` it means that you need to go fetch the results, if it's empty it means you fetched the results and there were none.  It is then the job of whatever is providing the lazy initialization abstraction layer to never expose the `null` collection externally.

Comment: @Kyralessa - No, it does not throw null if the IEnumerable it is querying is null, it will throw a null argument exception. Big difference.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung, apologies for confusing you.  Obviously the essential word here is "throw".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly. You need to be defensive all the time.

In fact, if `associatedColor` is null, that means there is something wrong, hence you need to handle it.

In fact, your code used to be wrapped in a try/catch block to handle exceptions, since, exceptions are "expensive", this is cheaper and nicer way to handle exceptional cases.

In any case, I would almost always use `FirstOrDefault` or something simirlar, like `SingleOrDefault` then I would do the null check.

Comment: Or use the upcoming [`?.` operator of C# 6](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The built in LINQ functions (like `.Where()` here) always return an empty enumerable if there are no results, not null. So there is no need to check for null after doing the `.Where()`

Depending on where ColorItems comes from, you should check for null on the object:

```
if (ColorItems != null) 
{
}
else
{
}
```

There's no need to put a try/catch block around the code, but you should be checking for null just to be safe. In fact, using try/catch in a scenario like this, where you can just check for a null object, is a bad programming practice.